# Dockerized spring-boot web service throws FileNotFound Exception

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, docker-container, file-not-found

I have tried to copy files from my windows machine to Docker container using the Docker File Command and reading those files from spring web service . Webservice throws an error file not found!

Here I am trying to copy my local directory src/nlp to /data container directoty

below are the avaialble docker volume

[image]

## Docker File

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

EXPOSE 8080

ARG JAR_FILE=/target/nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ADD ${JAR_FILE} nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ADD src/nlp  /data

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]`
```

## application.properties

```
server.port=8080
logging.level.radial.nlp=DEBUG
logging.file = mylogfile.log
nlp.learning.dir = /data/
```

Java

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(environment.getProperty("nlp.learning.dir")+ "/train/models/en/token/en-token.bin");
```

## Error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/train/models/en/token/en-token.bin (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please notice extra **slash** in your path before *train* dir
`/data//train/models/en/token/en-token.bin`

Consider changing reading line to:

`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(environment.getProperty("nlp.learning.dir")+ "train/models/en/token/en-token.bin");`

Comment: I have edited the error now, it was typo sorry for that.. can you check again now ? it is not related to extra slash i believe

Comment: try adding `RUN ls /data/train/models/en/token` or `RUN cat /data/train/models/en/token/en-token.bin` to your Dockerfile after adding resources. What is the output when you build an image?

Comment: It should contain filename/file content

Answer (score 1):

I have altered my maven plugin dependency , now it is working fine

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
<artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4.7</version>
<!-- Wire up to the default build phases -->
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>default</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>build</goal>
      <goal>push</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
  <repository>${project.artifactId}</repository>
  <buildArgs>
    <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
  </buildArgs>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have a file `src/nlp/train/models/en/token/en-token.bin` the same directory as you are building your container from.

```
parent/
├── Dockerfile
└── src/
    └── nlp/
        └── train/
            └── models/
                └── en/
                    └── token/
                        └── en-token.bin <--- does this exist?
```